# Docker exposed port unavailable on browser, though the former run works

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port, docker-machine, boot2docker

I use docker on Virtual Box and I try to add one more image-running.

The first 'run' that I had is

```
$ docker run -Pit --name rpython -p 8888:8888 -p 8787:8787 -p 6006:6006 -p 
8022:22 -v /c/Users/lenovo:/home/dockeruser/hosthome 
datascienceschool/rpython

$ docker port rpython
8888/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8888
22/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8022
27017/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32781
28017/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32780
5432/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32783
6006/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:6006
6379/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32782
8787/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8787
```

It works fine, on local browser through those tcp. 
But about the second 'running'

```
docker run -Pit -i -t -p 8888:8888 -p 8787:8787 -p 8022:22 -p 3306:3306 --
name ubuntu jhleeroot/dave_ubuntu:1.0.1

$ docker port ubuntu
22/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8022
3306/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:3306
8787/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8787
8888/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8888
```

It doesn't work.

```
root@90dd963fe685:/# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group 
default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
23: eth0@if24: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue 
state UP group default
link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
inet 172.17.0.2/16 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

Your first command ran an image (`datascienceschool/rpython`) that presumably kicked off a python app which must have listened to the port you were testing.

Your second command ran a different image (`jhleeroot/dave_ubuntu:1.0.1`) and from the pasted output you are only running a bash shell in that image. Bash isn't listening on these ports inside the container, so docker will forward to a closed port and the browser will see a closed connection.

Docker doesn't run the server for your listening ports, it relies on you to run that inside the container and it just forwards the requests.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps :)